# How can we run JavaScript in VS Code itself

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Can anyone tell me how can I run this JavaScript code in VS Code without node.js?

```
var a;
a = 0;
a++;
alert(a);
```

Comment: In the integrated terminal?

Comment: Open up the dev tools (e.g. option-cmd-i on MacOS). Go to the console. Paste your code. VScode will dutifully alert "1" in a modal. It's not clear though why you'd *want* to ever do this, or what you mean by "without node.js" since VScode is an electron app. Can you post more details?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to use NodeJS or a browser, you need a shell to run JavaScript. Here are a few:

1. http://www.jsdb.org/
2. http://javalikescript.free.fr/

Comment: You don't need that. VSCode embeds the chrome dev tools, including the Javascript console with full access to `window` including `alert`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're a beginner. If you want to try basic JavaScript code try plunker. it's easy for beginners. simply type your code in the .js file and click preview.

```
var a;
a = 0;
a++;
alert(a);
```

[Click here for above code in plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FTDrO3YPGkhagKxe?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

Leave a comment if you need any assistant.